# iperf3 What these results mean is it good/bad?

Tags: networking, iperf3

I have Xiaomi Router with openwrt installed and i used iperf to test my connection between my pc and router, i want to know is these results good or not?(i dont think its good, seems to be a lot of loss)

Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller

Xiaomi Mi WiFi AC1200 Router 4A Giga Version

OpenWrt 22.03.4 - r20123-38ccc47687

### [This is the first test with tcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwxte.png) //
[udp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFvcB.png)

[iperf3 -c 192.168.1.1 -f m -t 60 -i 5 -V -u -b 1G -P 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IspTI.png) //
[iperf3 -c 192.168.1.1 -f m -t 60 -i 5 -V -P 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcSfC.png)

Comment: Please be more careful with your edition when writing a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be much more "friendly" if you copy-pasted the output into the question rather than rely on people to click through to the screenshots.  What is the TCP Window size for the connection?  What is the round-trip-time?  How about  CPU utilization on either end?
Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime
is a common limitation to the performance of a TCP connection.